# ¿Cómo solucionar warning "ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib'" al compilar con gcc en macOS Sierra?

Tags: c, macos, gcc

Cuando intento compilar cualquier código C con gcc, me arroja el siguiente aviso:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib'
```

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es crear las carpetas que te indica el mensaje, esto se hace ejecutando en terminal la siguiente sentencia:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib
```